# Testing returned values for duplicates

Tags: php, testing, random, automated-tests

I've got a method that returns a string with predefined length of random alpha numbers.

I just let it run until it comes across a duplicate and breaks out of the loop and display the amount of generations it took before a duplicate was generated.

The loop numbers will be in the millions, and I am wondering if this really is good and efficient of testing it?

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: _I've got a method that returns a string with random alphanumbers._ Can you share that here ?

Comment: The best tool is a good brain to check the code you have and see what it actually does.... as we can't check your code, because we can't see any, you're reliant on your own brain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_search](https://www.php.net/array_search)

The function return the string and store it to an array.
Then use array_search to see if it is not FALSE and loop.

Answer (score -1):

Put The generated strings into an array as a key before outputting them.

```
$array[$alpha_string] = (isset($array[$alpha_string])) ? $array[$alpha_string] + 1 : 1;
```

Then check which items have a count > 1.